# Secure azure App Service using AD framework 4.5

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

i have a question about securing access to azure App Services, i have two App services, 
App service 1 and App service 2, my App service 1 is basically call my App service 2 , my App service 2 should be secured and allow access only from App Service 1 , i did used Ip Adress restrictions but my client said that its not enough so my question what can i use else to secure that access. the framework used here : 4.5. i did some search about Managed identities and Azure active directory but i dont know if i'm following the right path or not.

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register two AD Apps in Azure AD, one for client-app, and one for backend-app.
In Azure AD, grant permissions to allow the client-app to call the backend-app.

1. [Register an application in Azure AD to represent the API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#register-an-application-in-azure-ad-to-represent-the-api)
2. [Register another application in Azure AD to represent a client application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#register-another-application-in-azure-ad-to-represent-a-client-application)
3. [Grant permissions in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#grant-permissions-in-azure-ad)

You can also refer to this doc - [Scenario: Protected web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview).

Comment: I'll try this solution today and come back to you. thansk for your answer

Comment: While following the steps i saw there is a step called : enable OAuth 2.0 for client App, is that mandatory ? or its just a step to add token autorisation to the client app ? cauz here i'm kinda lost , is the OAuth 2.0 will be activated to secure communication between my client app and backend app ?

Comment: @ZIADIAOussama You mean this [step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad#enable-oauth-20-user-authorization-in-the-developer-console)? If so, ignore it. Just do the three steps as mentioned in the reply, then refer to the last link.