# Secure Azure App Service using Managed Identity (Asp.net Framework 4.7.2)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-managed-identity

i'm trying to secure communication between two azure app services. i tried to use Managed Identity for that but the only thing i can find is: securing Database access using Managed identity.

So i'm kinda lost here, is Managed Identity can secure communication between two app services or its just responsible to secure resources like Azure Storage, Sql Server?

Comment: The latter. For app to app communication you can look at azure ad or b2c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSI(Managed Identity) is used to secure Azure resources, essentially, it is a service principal in your Azure AD tenant, when granted corresponding permission, the MSI will be able to access corresponding resources.

To secure communication between two azure app services, MSI is not for such usage, you need to use Azure AD Apps to do this, register two AD Apps in Azure AD, one for client-app, and one for backend-app. If you enable the MSI of your App Service, it will just create a service principal i.e. enterprise application for you automatically without AD App(App registration).

Please refer to the steps I mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59768051/secure-azure-app-service-using-ad-framework-4-5).

Comment: i just tried to be sure 100M cauz i cant find on MSDN anything speaking about app to app communication with Managed Identity while my client is speaking about it, so i wanted to be sure that app to app communication is not possible with Managed identity otherwise we can use the solution that you mentioned in that post